# Gradle build two projects (project with Name and a project lib)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

today I have tried to create a Gradle Project in Eclipse. If the build process was finished the result was two seperate folders for no reason.

Gradle build a lib folder and a project folder. (Picture)
I dont find any soultion.
How can I force Gradle to build all in one like before?`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with newer Gradle versions, as indicated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857125

-> you could try it with gradle version 6.6

Comment: Thanks. Last months I find a workaround with Spring Init website. I stumbled upon the issue again. This gradle version solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have a build.gradle file in the lib folder, so it is probably interpreted as a gradle project itself. Maybe your main project has the lib folder registered as a [sub-project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)? You can check the content of the settings.gradle file.

The build.gradle file should probably be in the JUnitTestTutorial folder, next to the settings.gradle. The settings.gradle should not include any project as it IS the project.

Comment: thanks :) but how can I remove the sub-project before gradle build it?

Comment: Hard to say without all the context and files content. The build.gradle file should probably be in the JUnitTestTutorial folder, next to the settings.gradle.
The settings.gradle should not `include`  any project as it IS the project.

Comment: This is my setting gradle (new Project same Structure) I dont know why he build it in creating process.

Answer (score 1):

I had to move the `build.gradle` and the `src` folder from `lib` to my project, then delete `lib`. I also removed the `include` for `lib` from `gradle.settings`. Restart Eclipse and it sorted itself out, including dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I uninstalled Gradle and Eclipse, and I reinstalled the latest Eclipse and Gradle 6.8 and when creating the project, and I gave the `JAVA_HOME` path also.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was after downloading the gradle project you want to go to the settings.gradle remove the include(lib) and save project. Then refresh the gradle project. It should automatically add everything from lib to the project folder. To keep you computer clean delete the other lib file off the computer.