# Eclipse Gradle Wizard creates project with SubFolder -lib

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

When I create a Gradle project in Eclipse the result is a nested project with a -lib folder created automatically. Any ideas on why this is being created?

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce this in Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19) containing Eclipse Buildship 3.1.5.v20210113-0929, but not in Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) containing Eclipse Buildship 3.1.4.v20200326-1743. Make sure it has been reported here: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues

Comment: @user7291698 In my case, the lib was not created. Can you mention in which version of eclipse is this happening ?

Comment: I tried this with Eclipse 2020-03 and Eclipse 2021-03, same behaviour in both versions.

Answer (score 15):

I tested this on Eclipse 2021-03 using the latest gradle version 7.0-rc-1 and reproduced your issue where a nested project with a lib subproject was created. I then made a new Eclipse project specifying Gradle version 6.6 to be used and the resulting project was not nested. I suggest trying Gradle 6.6 and seeing if you get the same behavior I got. This might fix your project.

Also try running the `gradle init` command from the command line and see what project structure you get there. I tested this on my PC where I have gradle 5.6 as the default version and got a non nested structure. You can of course always manually modify your gradle project in a few minutes to not be nested.

Comment: Please also report your findings here: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues

Comment: @stuart - please "upvote" and "accept" this reply.  See also: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1077