# Gradle - Do not create subproject

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I installed Gradle in my Eclipse and I want to create a new project without subproject or nested project.
How can I do it?

-> in my settings.gradle:

**rootProject.name = 'ProjectName'**

**include('lib')** << *what I want to remove from my projects to build only one project*

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with an older Gradle version, e.g. version 6.6. This solved the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857125

Comment: Thank you sir! I checked the question you suggested!