# How to Revert Nested Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

[Workspace Image of the two projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB4FR.png)

Whenever I create a gradle project in eclipse, it splits it into two projects: the main folder and a lib folder which has the src folders. The lib folder is a nested project, how can I revert that and combine the the two projects?

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1077

Comment: @artavasdes: See the link howlger cited above: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1077.  Eclipse Issue 1077, in turn, cites this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857125/421195.  WORKAROUND: Use Gradle 6.x or lower.  PS: I love your avatar :)